# Calculating the Mean of a Truncated Multinormal Distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

First, I'm a little disappointed that Mathematica balks at:

```
Mean[TruncatedDistribution[{{0, Infinity}},MultinormalDistribution[{0}, {{1}}]]]
```

Second, is the numerical computation of means from truncated multinormal distributions so hard? Is anyone aware of a package that implements the algorithm of [Leppard and Tallis (1989)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2347752) (see [here](http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/apstat/249) for FORTRAN code) or anything like it?

**Edit**: rm asked for an example that fails to compute:

```
Mean[TruncatedDistribution[{{0, Infinity}, {0, Infinity}},
     MultinormalDistribution[{0.5, 1.5}, {{1., 0.3}, {0.3, 1.}}]]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to do serious statistical work, I would suggest to not use `Mean` and instead use specialized functions that work on distributions, such as `Expectation` and `NExpectation`. Although the documentation says that `Mean[dist]` gives the mean of the symbolic distribution, I suspect they meant it for basic distributions such as `NormalDistribution`, `BinomialDistribution`, etc., which were all there when `Mean` was written. `Mean` was last modified in version 6 and most probably is not aware of newer functions such as `TruncatedDistribution`, `MultinormalDistribution`, etc., which were all introduced in version 8.

So the equivalent code for your example is:

```
NExpectation[{x, y}, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
    TruncatedDistribution[
        {{0, Infinity}, {0, Infinity}}, 
        MultinormalDistribution[{0.5, 1.5}, {{1., 0.3}, {0.3, 1.}}]
    ]
]
(* {1.02198, 1.74957} *)
```

Using `Expectation` offers more flexibility than `Mean`, because you can now calculate the expectations of arbitrary quantities:

```
NExpectation[{Sin[x], y^3}, {x, y} \[Distributed] 
    TruncatedDistribution[
        {{0, Infinity}, {0, Infinity}}, 
        MultinormalDistribution[{0.5, 1.5}, {{1., 0.3}, {0.3, 1.}}]
    ]
]
(* {0.650673, 9.70065} *)
```

`NExpectation` still does not work with `MultinormalDistribution` with a single dimension... I don't know why exactly, but personally I would never use a *Multi*-something function to mean just 1 (which is the opposite of multi). I would suggest using a `Switch` and use `NormalDistribution` when you have a `MultinormalDistribution` of dimension 1.

Comment: Thanks. NExpectation is a big improvement. Although I'm getting NIntegrate::slwcon messages for my application, it's at least attempting an answer with 3 and 4 dimensions.

Comment: @Ian I also added some info on why you shouldn't use `Mean`. I don't think `Mean` knows about any of these distributions and probably cannot handle it

Answer (score 5):

The following works:

```
 Mean[TruncatedDistribution[{{0, Infinity}, {0, Infinity}}, 
 MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]]]

 (* {Sqrt[2/\[Pi]], Sqrt[2/\[Pi]]}*)
```

Note the syntax of arguments for `MultinormalDistribution` (it needs a vector for means and a matrix for variance), and for `TruncatedDistribution` (it needs a list of lists, one list of truncation limits for each dimension).

Example:

```
 Mean[TruncatedDistribution[{{0, Infinity}, {0, Infinity}}, 
 MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, \[Rho]}, {\[Rho], 1}}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: and in addition, use `NormalDistribution` to get an answer for the case in the question

Comment: @kguler True, that works. Now try using some numerical values that are not trivial.

Comment: @R.M Yes, but having to switch the function call programatically when the dimension is 1 is annoying.

Comment: @Ian Instead of making us waste time guessing at non-trivial values that might or might not work, why not just update your question with what didn't work for you?

Comment: @Ian Well, there's always `Switch`... note that I'm only mentioning it as an alternative. I suspect the reason might be due to the fact that `Mean` sees the dimension as 1 and calculates the expectation of `x`, when technically, it should be the expectation of `{x}`. You can also see this issue arise when you use `PDF` with your truncated distribution