# Expression for variance of a truncated distribution as a function of the point of truncation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, evaluation, distributions

I am working on a project where I need to calculate variance of a truncated distribution. Suppose $X$ has some distribution and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I am interested in $var(X|X\leq x)$. Given some distribution and values of its parameters, e.g., exponential with $\lambda=1$, how do I ask Mathematica for $var(X|X\leq x)$ such that I get a symbolic expression (function of $x$).

As an example, consider:

```
dist = TruncatedDistribution[{-Infinity, x}, ExponentialDistribution[1]]
```

When I ask for

```
Variance[dist]
```

Mathematica does not give me an expression. Doing

```
Expectation[z^2, z \[Distributed] dist] - Expectation[z, z \[Distributed] dist]^2
```

or

```
Moment[dist, 2] - Moment[dist, 1]^2
```

produces a symbolic expression. I am trying to understand why I get different answers and ultimately how to do things so that I get a symbolic expression (for as many distributions as possible).

The accepted answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9865/calculating-the-mean-of-a-truncated-multinormal-distribution) seems to suggest that `Expectation` works better than `Mean` (and thus, by extension `Variance`). Should I expect `Moment` and `Expectation` to work equally well (I would guess that `Moment` uses `Expectation`)? Are there even better ways I am unaware of?

Comment: There is a problem with notation in this question.  You are seeking  $Var(X | X \leq b)$ for some parameter $b$ .... not as the OP has written:  $Var(X | X \leq x)$. Note that $X$ is a random variable, and $x$ is typically the outcome of that random variable, so you cannot condition the outcome of the variable on itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

You just need to restrict `x` to being positive

```
dist = TruncatedDistribution[{-Infinity, x}, ExponentialDistribution[1]]

(* TruncatedDistribution[{0, x}, ExponentialDistribution[1]] *)

m = Assuming[x > 0, Mean[dist]]

(* (E^-x (-1 + E^x - x))/(1 - Cosh[x] + Sinh[x]) *)

sd = Assuming[x > 0, StandardDeviation[dist]]

(* Sqrt[-((2 + x^2 - 2 Cosh[x])/((-1 + E^x) (1 - Cosh[x] + Sinh[x])))] *)

var = Assuming[x > 0, Variance[dist]]

(* -((2 + x^2 - 2 Cosh[x])/((-1 + E^x) (1 - Cosh[x] + Sinh[x]))) *)

var == Assuming[x > 0, 
   Expectation[z^2, z \[Distributed] dist] - 
    Expectation[z, z \[Distributed] dist]^2] // Simplify

(* True *)

var == Assuming[x > 0, Moment[dist, 2] - Moment[dist, 1]^2] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: It seems the assumption of `x` being positive is because the distribution the OP picked only has positive support on positive real numbers.  That restriction isn't necessary when, for example, a normal distribution is used.

Comment: Thank you, this is ''easy'' solution to $Variance$ giving me different answer relative to $Expectation$ and $Moment$ (which never occurred to me would work and thus went untried).